# Redis: 'Get - Check Condition - Increase' with locking key

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to make a task scheduling program on node server.
and, the server will run on multiple computer.
so, I need to `in memory database` to share server state.

I wrote a code like below.

```js
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const redis = createClient();

const notify = () => {
  const runningTaskCount = redis.get('running_task_count');
  if (runningTaskCount >= 10) return;

  redis.incr('running_task_count');

  const taskId = redis.lpop('task_id_queue');
  const task = new Task(taskId);
  task.run();

  task.on('end', () => {
    redis.decr('running_task_count');
    notify();
  });
};

const add = (taskId) => {
  redis.rpush('task_id_queue', taskId);
  notify();
};
```

if only one server running, no problem in this code.
but, multiple server running, running_task_count can be over 10.

So, I want to do like below

```
Lock 'running_task_count'
Get 'running_task_count'

if (running_task_count >= 10) {
  Unlock 'running_task_count'
  return
}

Incr 'running_task_count'
Unlock 'running_task_count'

(go on...)
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: This maybe helps to you: https://redis.io/topics/distlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis has the ability to run server-side logic via Lua scripts (see the [`EVAL` command](https://redis.io/commands/eval)). Script execution is atomic, so race conditions are eliminated. A script like the following can do the job:

```
local val = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
if val >= 10 then
  return
end
redis.call('INCR', KEYS[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for sth like [redlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redlock)

```js
// the string identifier for the resource you want to lock
var resource = 'running_task_count';

// the maximum amount of time you want the resource locked in milliseconds,
// keeping in mind that you can extend the lock up until
// the point when it expires
var ttl = 1000;

redlock.lock(resource, ttl).then(function(lock) {

    // ...do something here...
    redis.incr('running_task_count')

    // unlock your resource when you are done
    return lock.unlock()
    .catch(function(err) {
        // we weren't able to reach redis; your lock will eventually
        // expire, but you probably want to log this error
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```